# Is there a way to have Vim reconnect to a different X server?

Tags: vim, xserver

I am using Vim inside tmux over an ssh connection on a remote machine. I access the remote server from several locations including work and at home. This usually causes stale $DISPLAY variables and associated problems, most of which I have resolved except for one:

If I have a vim session already opened, is there a way to change which X server it is connected to without closing and re-opening it? I need to be able to do this so I can copy snippets of text from Vim using the X clipboard. I normally keep multiple vertical splits, linebreak and line numbers on, so doing this through tmux is usually a giant hassle and would prefer to do it with vim.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [xpra](http://xpra.org/) to display a running X11 program (specifically, vim) on different X11 servers.

This program functions for X11 programs like GNU screen or tmux do for terminal programs. xpra provides an X server for running programs and itself acts as an X client for the X server for the user's display.

You mention that you are running vim through tmux; you should maybe run vim outside of tmux and use xpra directly. As far as I know the program has to be run through xpra from the start.

Comment: Not quite sure if this is what I want... How would xpra help me to switch Vim from a different (potentially dead/disconnected) X server to the one that I'm connecting from?

Comment: I've expanded my answer. It works just like tmux switching between terminals.

Answer (score 3):

There's a relatively new command called xrestore which does this:

```
:xrestore :0
```

https://groups.google.com/g/vim_dev/c/G54XTJHAqXI

https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3649

Comment: The first link is broken for me. Will give this a try soon.

Comment: Thanks: **awesome**. `:xrestore :10` when reconnecting to a tmux session via SSH helps against `E353: Nothing in register +` when trying to (copy,) paste..

Answer (score 2):

If the sole purpose of using X is to transfer large amount of text, consider using [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) instead.

From within vim mark the lines you're interested in and do `:w /tmp/foo`

From a shell (or suspend vim using `ctrl-z` ; `bg`) do

```
scp your_username@remotehost.edu:/tmp/foo /some/local/directory
```

Comment: Not quite. I was misleading in the original question; I actually frequently want to copy small snippets of text from vim. I normally keep vertical splits, linebreak and line numbers on, so doing this through tmux is a giant hassle usually.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line to `~/.tmux.conf` on the server and reloaded the tmux sessions there. This one-liner does the trick of automatically attaching to the local X-server when I connect to the tmux-session from multiple local clients using SSH. Each local client has its own X-server (X410 in my case).

```
set-option -g update-environment " DISPLAY"
```

How it works? According [this post](https://goosebearingbashshell.github.io/2017/12/07/reset-display-variable-in-tmux.html), the line is supposed to refresh the `$DISPLAY` variable for all panes. Here is another [related post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/146631/240390).

---

Setup: all my local clients are Windows 10 machines, running WSL (Pengwin distro as WSL2). My X-server is X410 downloaded from the Windows Store. The server that hosts the Tmux+vim sessions is a Linux Mint machine. On the server, the Tmux version is `3.3a`.

Per my workflow, this means a lot. Especially that I don't have to repeat the following procedures: 1. SSH from another local machine; 2. Finding that clipboard won't work; 3. Save the work, exit Vim; 4. Start a new pane in the current Tmux session, and 5. Start Vim again, trying to load back to where I was.